# Content to stay the same when window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to keep my content from coming together upon a window re-size. I use columns in my website in a newspaper style. When a user would downsize the window the columns push together becoming unreadable. Is it possible to keep the content from doing this using JavaScript or perhaps jQuery? Thank You

Comment: Since you're talking about styling, CSS is probably the better tool for the job.  Something like `min-width` for example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).  Perhaps if you could demonstrate the specific issue with some code which reproduces it.  I also recommend debugging the styling using your browser's debugging tools to see which style rules are affecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the effect you want.  You can't stop the browser from getting smaller, but you can change how you react to it.  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) has some options for reflowing when the screen width gets small.  Even easier is to just set a `min-width` css style property on the containing content and the width will only shrink that far before giving a horizontal scrollbar.